# Powershell Rename File Regular Expression

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting

I have in a folder a lot of .pdf files with the naming format of whatevername space random code starting with `U.pdf` and I want to remove whatever is the naming before U.

**Example Name Format:**

`Alex U153569.pdf` -> should be renamed to `U153569.pdf`

This is what I have so far:

```
foreach ($test in $testpdf) {
    Get-ChildItem -Filter *.pdf | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.name -Replace ????????? }
}
```

What should be the correct one?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$_.name -Replace '.*\s(?=U)'
```

Answer (score 0):

Without testing you should be able to use the split operator (no need for a regular expression). You can split on a space as below and index into the second split `[1]`

```
$testpdf = Get-ChildItem *.pdf
foreach ($test in $testpdf) {
    Rename-Item $test.name -NewName (($test.name -split " ")[1])
}
```